# Rewrite url for video

Tags: asp.net, video, url-rewriting

I am newbie with asp.net. I have a url of video `http://localhost/video/file.mp4` , but i want to serve url like `http://localhost/34567fghft/file.mp4` to make timeout for url, is there some solution to my question? Sr for my english, im stuct around with this, waiting for your answers, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can on `Global.asax`, and on `Application_BeginRequest` to get the requested path, split it, see if has expired or not, manipulate the string and send him ether to an error page, ether rewrite it to the real path:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{       
    string cTheFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path;

    if (cTheFile.EndsWith("/file.mp4", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        // manipulate your string to see if is expired...
        string[] keys = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.Split('/');

        // get the 34567fghft part
        if (IfExpired(keys[keys.Length - 1]))
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("ExpiredMessage.aspx", true);
            return ;
        }
        else
        {
            HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("http://localhost/video/file.mp4", false);
        }
    }
}
```

Please note this code is the idea on how you do it. Is need some better string manipulation and error check.

Comment: Thanks, I have try this, but it doesn't work with me. Static file request is not pass Application_BeginRequest, so i can't handle mp4 request. I have wrote a class inherited IHttpHandler to catch mp4 request, and RewritePath to the real url, but Player can not play :-s

Comment: @dugchie Ether write a handler to give the file, either setup your IIS, so this static file pass from asp.net